# Should all models be represented in DB, or better to make only a controller if modell is not represented in DB?

Tags: laravel, routes, naming

I wonder about the route leading to the welcome-page in my project. You reach it with the '/'-route .

Where should the method handling this route be and what is the correct structure behind it?

I get two ideas spontaneously:

1. Make a model named something like ***Home*** and put the method in ***HomeController***

   (Con: I thought all modells should be represented in DB?)

...

2. Make only a controller named ***HomeController***, no model

   (Con: Feels wrong to have a controller for a modell that does not exist?)

What is correct?

Comment: ' Feels wrong to have a controller for a model that does not exist?'. Controllers are not only to handle models. so don't feel bad.

Comment: 1. Not all models should have controller. Sometimes you just want to see the relationship between tables only. For example, User has Status, but you don't need to create StatusController for that. You can simply access it through $user->status->name, or something like that..

2. Yes you can have controller without model. Controller is the processing part. Sometimes you just need to create a function to delete all files in a perticular folder. You won't be needing a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll leave it here.

Both `Model` and `Controller` are just `Class`. If you take a look at your `HomeController` and your `User.php` model you'll see they extend `Controller` and `Model` Classes, respectively.

As many said there is no need to have 1 to 1 relationship between Controllers and Models.

Invest some time to learn basics of OOP and you will see that you can have as much classes as you want, and there are many ways to relate them. Some of the Classes are Controllers, some are Models and some are something completely else, like Exceptions. But at all times keep in mind that, in the end, they are just Classes implementing some interface, using some traits, and extending other Classes.

It's worth to do this at the start of your learning process. It will steepen your learning curve a bit but in the long run it's well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a model for each controller or vice versa, just add them as needed according to your application: need CRUD actions or other interaction with your model. Try creating a `WecolmeController` as the `HomeController` is the default one for after login features (or change it accordingly if needed).